# Testing type of function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a function like so:

```
type Entry = PageBasic | PageHome | PostCollection | PostProduct;

export default (entry: Entry): Params => {
  const contentType = entry.sys.contentType.sys.id;

  if (contentType ==='pageBasic') {
    return { slug: entry.fields.slug };
  }

  if (contentType === 'pageCollection') {
    return { collection: entry.fields.slug };
  }

  if (contentType === 'postProduct') return {
    collection: entry.fields.collection.fields.slug,
    product: entry.fields.slug,
  };

  return {};
};
```

My types for PageBasic, PostCollection and PostProduct are all different. Some have the `fields.slug` and `fields.collection` data and some don't. My if statements confirm to me which entry type I'm dealing with e.g. if the `contentType === 'pageCollection'` then I'm dealing with `PostCollection` type. However Typescript doesn't know that. Is there a way for me to tell it if my condition is true, then the type of the entry param is PostCollection or something?

The only other way I know to do this is adding lots more conditional statements to check if the keys exist, which seems pointless when I already know they will based on my conditional statements. e.g:

```
export default (entry: Entry): Params => {
  const contentType = entry.sys.contentType.sys.id;

  if (contentType === CT_PAGE_BASIC) {
    if ('slug' in entry.fields) return { slug: entry.fields.slug };
  }

  if (contentType === CT_POST_COLLECTION) {
    if ('slug' in entry.fields) return { collection: entry.fields.slug };
  }

  if (contentType === CT_POST_PRODUCT) return {
    ...'collection' in entry.fields && { collection: entry.fields.collection.fields.slug },
    ...'slug' in entry.fields && { product: entry.fields.slug },
  };

  return {};
};
```

Comment: What's wrong with `return {slug: (<PageBasic>entry.fields).slug };`?

Comment: ^^ To put it more positively **:-)**: How about a [type assertion](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions)? `return {slug: (<PageBasic>entry).fields.slug };` or `return {slug: (entry as PageBasic).fields.slug };`

Comment: This solution throws a Typescript error: `Property 'slug' does not exist on type 'PageBasic.` even though slug does exist on PageBasic.

Comment: Ah I think it was just the placement of the brackets. All working now (see answer from Jack Bashford).

Comment: We could probably help you better if you provided a [mcve], reducing it to (say) two types and providing the full example. From the above, I suspect we could avoid type assertions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can - use a [type assertion](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions):

```
if (contentType ==='pageBasic') {
  return { slug: <PageBasic>(entry).fields.slug };
}
```

You could also return an object with conditionals:

```
export default (entry: Entry): Params => {
  const contentType = entry.sys.contentType.sys.id;
  return { 
    ...(contentType ==='pageBasic' ? { slug: (<PageBasic>entry).fields.slug } : 0),
    ...(contentType === 'pageCollection' ? { collection: (<PostCollection>entry).fields.slug } : 0),
    ...(contentType === 'postProduct' ? { collection: (<PostProduct>entry).fields.collection.fields.slug, product: (<PostProduct>entry).fields.slug } : 0)
  };
};
```

Comment: Awesome, this works a treat. My linting preferred me to write it as `return { slug: (entry as PageBasic).fields.slug };` but it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: No problem @Coop, always glad to help. I've also added another part to my answer that might solve your conditional problem.